# Javascript And Query

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and trying to add a and Query to a js file.
I have added a checkbox this is required to be checked for the submit button to show.
In the original there was already one checkbox with the js query but I have added a second. How do I make the js only allow the button to be clicked when both are checked?

The current code for the js is

```
jQuery('.check_policy').on('click', function(){
        if(jQuery('#policycheck') .is(':checked')){
            jQuery("#listingsubmitBTN").prop('disabled',false);
            jQuery("#listingsubmitBTN").removeClass('dissablebutton');
        }
        else{
            jQuery("#listingsubmitBTN").prop('disabled',true);
            jQuery("#listingsubmitBTN").addClass('dissablebutton');
        }
    });
```

The second check box I have added is called policycheck_2

Thanks in advance for any help. I think this could be one of many js questions

Mark

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.check_policy').on('click', function(){
    if(jQuery('#policycheck').is(':checked') && jQuery('#policycheck_2').is(':checked')){
        jQuery("#listingsubmitBTN").prop('disabled',false).removeClass('dissablebutton');
    }
    else{
        jQuery("#listingsubmitBTN").prop('disabled',true).addClass('dissablebutton');
    }
});
```

Edit: Just add an AND (&&) operator with the same syntax with the new ID as the first one in the if statement. 
I'll also shortened the rest a little bit, looks nicer. :-)

Comment: "I am new to JavaScript" I think an explanation of your answer would be appropriate. Explain to the OP why their solution did not work, and explain what you changed and why it is a working solution

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged.

Comment: Thanx for notifying me, I am new here as well.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. If only the first checkbox is checked the button still works

Comment: @mark-milton There are two other working solutions here. Can you take a look at them and see if they are what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

- Separate the responsibilities.
- Bind the click event to the checkboxes. The handler only has to trigger the event on the specific button.
- Bind a custom event to your button which validates the checked boxes.

**Use this condition to disable or enable:**

```
$('.check_policy').length !== $('.check_policy:checked').length
```

```js
$('.check_policy').on('click', function() {
  // Here we trigger the custom event.
  $('#listingsubmitBTN').trigger('validatechecked'); 
  
  // Now this handler only trigger events to specific elements and not 
  // everything mixed here.
});

$('#listingsubmitBTN').on('validatechecked', function() {     
    $(this).prop('disabled', $('.check_policy').length !== $('.check_policy:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class='check_policy' type='checkbox'>Check policy#1
<p>
<input class='check_policy' type='checkbox'>Check policy#2
<p>
<input type='button' id='listingsubmitBTN' value="Click me!" disabled>
```

Comment: This change also doesn't work only button works with just one for the checkboxes being checked

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that your `if` statement is not checking if **both** checkboxes are checked - it still only checks to see if `#policycheck` is checked to determine the disabled status of the button. A simple fix would be to add the `jQuery("#policycheck_2").is(":checked")` to your `if` statement, and your code will work - however, you can leverage using an expression in the `prop` setter function, as well as the `toggleClass` function to simplify/shorten/clean-up your code a bit.

Here's an example of what that would look like:

```js
jQuery('.check_policy').on('click', function() {
  var bothChecked = jQuery("#policycheck").is(":checked") && jQuery("#policycheck_2").is(":checked");
  jQuery("#listingsubmitBTN").prop("disabled", !bothChecked).toggleClass("dissablebutton", !bothChecked);
  console.log("button", bothChecked ? "enabled" : "disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="policycheck" />
<input type="checkbox" id="policycheck_2" />
<button class="check_policy">Check Policy</button>
```

Comment: This change also doesn't work only button works with just one for the checkboxes being checked

Comment: @mark-milton Can you post your updated code? Something else has to be wrong here..